# Reverse Proxy Websocket Connection from NGINX to WSO2 API Manager

Tags: nginx, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am having problem reverse proxying the websocket connection from NGINX to the WSO API Manager. My Nginx configuration is as below:

```
location /echowebsocket {
    proxy_pass  http://api_ws_servers;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

so when I do `ws://myhost/echowebsocket/1.0` the connection will timed out. It works when I try it locally `ws://localhost/echowebsocket 1.0` with nodejs ws client.

The `api_ws_servers` upstream is pointing to right IP address and port number (9099). I am pretty sure that is not the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, it turns out the port 9099 is not being opened by the sysadmin. I was assuming it has been opened since they opened it on our staging server. There is nothing wrong with NGinx configuration.